# R how to convert the data.frame into time series one by one

Tags: r, dataframe, repeat, xts

I have a series of data.frame like

```
  r t    
1 x 2

2 y 3

3 z 4
```

but I want to convert these three into time series, like

```
q = xts(as.matrix(data[1,]), order.by = "2011-09-28")
qq = xts(as.matrix(data[2,]), order.by = "2011-09-28")
qqq = xts(as.matrix(data[3,]), order.by = "2011-09-28")
```

My question is that since each time I only change rownames (1,2,3) and the names q qq qqq, may I sum them up into only one comment? like implement some functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df=data.frame(list(r=c("x","y","z"),t=c(2,3,4)))
dfx=as.xts(df,order.by=rep(as.POSIXct("2011-09-28"),nrow(df)))
```